# how do i access one record from query results in python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

hi i have this query and its result i was trying to access record by record at a time but im not able to

```
select_migration_db = "SELECT B.rmt_n, A.prr_id, A.rp_ID FROM mo_TRAC A, T_sft_init_prr B WHERE A.rp_id=B.int_prr_id AND A.STATUS='Sc' AND A.PHASE='first' AND A.WAVE='first'"
def my_query(query,cursor):
    conn = oracle.connect(user=user,password=pwd,dsn = host,encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return cursor.fetchall()

rows =my_query
for r in rows:
    print (r)
```

```
the table result looks like
rmt_n         prr_id          rp_ID       
                 
ss_tt_1        1456           767
rr_mm_2        663            889
ss_op_3        8894           999
```

Comment: Look at cx_Oracle examples like https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/bind_insert.py and https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/bind_query.py.  Also, you should upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of really basic errors:

- You're not calling the function  with `my_query(select_migration_db)`.
- The function doesn't need `cursor` to be a parameter
- The function never executes the query

```
select_migration_db = "SELECT B.rmt_n, A.prr_id, A.rp_ID FROM mo_TRAC A, T_sft_init_prr B WHERE A.rp_id=B.int_prr_id AND A.STATUS='Sc' AND A.PHASE='first' AND A.WAVE='first'"

def my_query(query):
    conn = oracle.connect(user=user,password=pwd,dsn = host,encoding="UTF-8")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return cursor.fetchall()

rows = my_query(select_migration_db)
for r in rows:
    print(r[0])
    input("are you ready for the next row?")
```

The function assumes you've set global variables `user`, `pwd`, and `host` appropriately for your Oracle connection.

Comment: what i need exactly is getting one record which is for example:ss_tt_1 and then the other one and so on one by one

Comment: Each time through the loop `r` is just one record.

Comment: If you just want one column, you can index it: `r[0]` gets the first column.

Comment: i mean the first record of first column how do we get it

Comment: That's in `rows[0][0]`

Comment: You mean first field of first record. Or first column of first record?

Comment: @SikehJaphet What's the difference? The OP's English is not good, so I'm interpreting it liberally.

Comment: the first field

Comment: r[0][0] not working

Comment: What is it doing instead of what you want? It will raise an exception if the query didn't return any rows, but other than that it should work.

Comment: Why do you call `fetchall()` if you only want one row? Use `fetchone()` to get just the first row.

Comment: is not working also what i need is one record at time and then the second and then the third

Comment: I clearly don't understand what you mean by one record at a time. Each time through the loop you get one record. You can do all the processing you want with it, then repeat the loop to get the next record.

Comment: If you don't want a loop, you can return the cursor from the function instead of the list. Then call `next(cursor)` every time you want to process another row.

Comment: each time i got one column so for example i want get  first s ss_tt_1   and then     
rr_mm_2      and the 
ss_op_3 separately one by one ???

Comment: `for r in rows: print(r[0])`

Comment: it will give me the whole column

Comment: You can do other things in the loop, like ask the user for input before going to the next row.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: I already updated the answer.

Comment: ok thanks i got some more questions regarding of some project if you have time we can discuses

Answer (score 0):

```
select_migration_db = "SELECT B.rmt_n, A.prr_id, A.rp_ID FROM mo_TRAC A, T_sft_init_prr B WHERE A.rp_id=B.int_prr_id AND A.STATUS='Sc' AND A.PHASE='first' AND A.WAVE='first'"

    conn = oracle.connect(user=user,password=pwd,dsn = host,encoding="UTF-8")


with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(select_migration_db)
            while True:
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                if row is None:
                    break
                print(row)
```